# jquery autocomplete showing data but not open links onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to buils search like imdb.com but my autocomplete search showing data. but i want to open search results works on click. Means hyperlink enabled for every search but onclick on search results not working. Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

using this

https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
                minChars: 1,
                source: function(term, suggest){
                    term = term.toLowerCase();
                    var choices = ['ActionScript', 'AppleScript', 'Asp', 'Assembly', 'BASIC', 'Batch', 'C', 'C++', 'CSS', 'Clojure', 'COBOL', 'ColdFusion', 'Erlang', 'Fortran', 'Groovy', 'Haskell', 'HTML', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Lisp', 'Perl', 'PHP', 'PowerShell', 'Python', 'Ruby', 'Scala', 'Scheme', 'SQL', 'TeX', 'XML'];
                    var suggestions = [];
                    for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                        if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                    suggest(suggestions);
                }
            });
            $('#advanced-demo').autoComplete({
                minChars: 0,
                source: function(term, suggest){
                    term = term.toLowerCase();
                    var choices = [['Australia', 'au'], ['Austria', 'at'], ['Brasil', 'br'], ['Bulgaria', 'bg'], ['Canada', 'ca'], ['China', 'cn'], ['Czech Republic', 'cz'], ['Denmark', 'dk'], ['Finland', 'fi'], ['France', 'fr'], ['Germany', 'de'], ['Hungary', 'hu'], ['India', 'in'], ['Italy', 'it'], ['Japan', 'ja'], ['Netherlands', 'nl'], ['Norway', 'no'], ['Portugal', 'pt'], ['Romania', 'ro'], ['Russia', 'ru'], ['Spain', 'es'], ['Swiss', 'ch'], ['Turkey', 'tr'], ['USA', 'us']];
                    var suggestions = [];
                    for (i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                        if (~(choices[i][0]+' '+choices[i][1]).toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) suggestions.push(choices[i]);
                    suggest(suggestions);
                },
                renderItem: function (item, search){
                    search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
                    var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
                    return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-langname="'+item[0]+'" data-lang="'+item[1]+'" data-val="'+search+'"><img src="img/'+item[1]+'.png"> '+item[0].replace(re, "<b>$1</b>")+'</div>';
                },
                onSelect: function(e, term, item){
                    console.log('Item "'+item.data('langname')+' ('+item.data('lang')+')" selected by '+(e.type == 'keydown' ? 'pressing enter or tab' : 'mouse click')+'.');
                    $('#advanced-demo').val(item.data('langname')+' ('+item.data('lang')+')');
                }
            });
        });
        if (~window.location.href.indexOf('http')) {
            (function() {var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);})();
            (function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=114593902037957";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
            $('#github_social').html('\
                <iframe style="float:left;margin-right:15px" src="//ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=Pixabay&repo=jQuery-autoComplete&type=watch&count=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="110" height="20"></iframe>\
                <iframe style="float:left;margin-right:15px" src="//ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=Pixabay&repo=jQuery-autoComplete&type=fork&count=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="110" height="20"></iframe>\
            ');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @adiga added  code by editng question

Comment: There are 2 autocompletes here. Which one isn't working? See how to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Trim all the junk arrays and post only the code that is relevant to the question. It's painful to go through with scrolling.

Comment: I want this one should changed to on click  how can i do that `onSelect: function(e, term, item){
                    console.log('Item "'+item.data('langname')+' ('+item.data('lang')+')" selected by '+(e.type == 'keydown' ? 'pressing enter or tab' : 'mouse click')+'.');
                    $('#advanced-demo').val(item.data('langname')+' ('+item.data('lang')+')');
                }`